# Echo text using is_tag

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tags, conditional-tags

I've been trying to echo some text to all single pages that are part of tag_ID 129

This is the code that I used

```
<?php 

if ( is_tag( '129' )){

echo '<p> test 2</p>';
    }
?>
```

so far no luck.. The image attached is too show where I'm getting the info

any help would be great! thanks

https://wpengine.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=ait-items&tag_ID=129&post_type=ait-item&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dait-items%26post_type%3Dait-item

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `is_tag` does:

> Determines whether the query is for an existing tag archive page.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tag/

`is_tag` and other functions such as `is_search` etc don't tell you anything about a post, they tell you if you're on a search archive, or a tag archive,  etc

So `is_tag` is true on `example.com/tag/example` but would be false on a post because that's not a tag archive.

Instead what you want, is `has_tag` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/

Some final notes though:

- Don't hardcode term IDs! Use the slug/name if you really have to hardcode things. If you ever delete that tag by accident, or have to do a migration, your code would stop working.
- Indent your code, it'll avoid entire types of bugs, and make it easier to read ( especially for people who might answer questions :p )
- If in doubt, check the official docs at https://developer.wordpress.org/